# Flutter if then nothing else then show button(but only if item not exist

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement

I have a button that only shows when I scan an item but...
What I want is that the button only shows when the scanned code not already exists.

The code now is:

```
Column(
          children: [
            if (_scanBarcode.isEmpty) ...[
              Text("NIKS")
            ] else  ...[
              ElevatedButton.icon(onPressed: () => _showFormadd(null), icon: Icon( // <-- Icon
                Icons.download,
                size: 24.0,
              ),

                label: Text('Artikel staat nog niet in de database : $_scanBarcode\n',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, height: 1.5)
                ), // <-- Text
              ),
              ]
            ]
            ),
```

I have to do something with the else statement and I guess i have to change that to an Elseif but I dont know what is best to do then..

I thought about Else if and then contains or compare but when I want to compare with a dynamic list then it is not working.

Can someone say if Im in the right direction or that I have to use a different way?

Answer (score 0):

To show the button only when the scanned code does not already exist in a dynamic list, you can use the **contains** method to check if the list contains the scanned code.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    if (_scanBarcode.isEmpty) ...[
      Text("NIKS")
    ] else if (!_yourDynamicList.contains(_scanBarcode)) ...[
      ElevatedButton.icon(
        onPressed: () => _showFormadd(null),
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.download,
          size: 24.0,
        ),
        label: Text(
          'Artikel staat nog niet in de database : $_scanBarcode\n',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, height: 1.5),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ],
)
```

Replace **_yourDynamicList** with the actual name of your dynamic list that contains the scanned codes. This code will only show the button when **_scanBarcode** is not present in the list.

Comment: Thanks, it works a simple list but when i want to use a list with column names and want to use contains to the title column in the database then I have to add something more but I go and try with the example you gave me :)